# How to avoid extra renders in my component to use react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to use react hooks instead of class-based components and have some problem with performance.

Code:

```
import React, { memo, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

let counter = -1;

function useToggle(initialValue) {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const toggler = useCallback(() => setToggleValue(!toggleValue), [
    toggleValue,
    setToggleValue
  ]);
  return [toggleValue, toggler];
}

const Header = memo(({ onClick }) => {
  counter = counter + 1;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HEADER</h1>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Toggle Menu</button>
      <div>Extra Render: {counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
});

const Dashboard = memo(() => {
  const [visible, toggle] = useToggle(false);
  const handleMenu = useCallback(
    () => {
      toggle(!visible);
    },
    [toggle, visible]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Header onClick={handleMenu} />
      <div>Dashboard with hooks</div>
      {visible && <div>Menu</div>}
    </>
  );
});

export default Dashboard;
```

Here is an example of what I wanna do: [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/w70xnvpwy8).

As you see, there are extra renders in my Header component.
My question: Is it possible to avoid extra renders to use react-hooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your custom hook `useToggle` to use functional state setter, like this

```
function useToggle(initialValue) {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const toggler = useCallback(() => setToggleValue(toggleValue => !toggleValue));
  return [toggleValue, toggler];
}
```

and use it like this :

```
const Dashboard = memo(() => {
  const [visible, toggle] = useToggle(false);
  const handleMenu = useCallback(
    () => {
      toggle();
    }, []
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Header onClick={handleMenu} />
      <div>Dashboard with hooks</div>
      {visible && <div>Menu</div>}
    </>
  );
});
```

Complete example : https://codesandbox.io/s/z251qjvpw4

#### Edit

This can be simpler (thanks to @DoXicK)

```
function useToggle(initialValue) {
  const [toggleValue, setToggleValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const toggler = useCallback(() => setToggleValue(toggleValue => !toggleValue), [setToggleValue]);
  return [toggleValue, toggler];
}


const Dashboard = memo(() => {
  const [visible, toggle] = useToggle(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Header onClick={toggle} />
      <div>Dashboard with hooks</div>
      {visible && <div>Menu</div>}
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's my first time to use hooks and it's my fail because I miss this
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Currently, your example must recreate a new callback for Toggle, since toggle receives a new "toggler" everytime you run `useToggle`. It can be made easier without having to do another `useCallaback`: `const toggler = useCallback(() => setToggleValue(toggleValue => !toggleValue), [setToggleValue])`. Since the setter never changes, your callback will always return the same. then you don't need `handleMenu` at all.

Comment: In your Dashboard code, you set the array parameter to []. This is not documented in React and although it works, I question the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with `useCallback` get invalidate too often. (there is a conversation about this on React repo here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14099)

since `useCallback` will be invalidated every time `toggle` value change and return a new function, then passing a new `handleMenu` function to `<Header />` cause it re-render.

A workaround solution is to create a custom `useCallback` hook:

(Copied from https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14099#issuecomment-457885333)

```js
function useEventCallback(fn) {
  let ref = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  });
  return useMemo(() => (...args) => (0, ref.current)(...args), []);
}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/1o87xrnj37

Answer (score -1):

If you use the callback pattern to update state, you would be able to avoid extra re-renders since the function need not be created again and again and you use just create `handleMenu` on first render

```
const Dashboard = memo(() => {
  const [visible, toggle] = useToggle(false);
  const handleMenu = useCallback(() => {
    toggle(visible => !visible);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header onClick={handleMenu} />
      <div>Dashboard with hooks</div>
      {visible && <div>Menu</div>}
    </>
  );
});
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/93p5vm81mo)

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP had?

Comment: @rrd, I am sorry I added my own working code while editing OP question. I updated the post again with he correct code